# What are the downsides (if any) of having a PhD to work in the software industry? Any about having technology certifications?

Tags: phd, certification

So you can take me seriously, let me first introduce myself: I am a PhD student about to finish my thesis and, thinking about future employment, I am considering to obtain an Oracle Java Certification, ammong other things.

The question I ask may sound odd, but I found this comic: http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=56

Apparently, having a PhD is considered as a downside when applying for a job in the **software industry**. I don't see how that may be funny, and the reason behind it.

Moreover, and actually what made me make this question here: having taken a course in a technology is considered much worse, for instance, than having grammar errors in the resume or mentioning your skills using MS Word. One guy even say "The point about certifications is dead-on". Other person comments "For most of the good Cisco certifications you HAVE to take the course, otherwise you will epic fail".

This make me wonder if the problem is to had taken the course to get the certification, not the certification itself. Maybe they mean that showing in your CV that you completed a 10 hours online course on "Starting with C language" is perhaps not a good idea. Otherwise I don't understand.

I hope someone can shed some light on this.

Comment: A PhD is, from the industry POV, less practical than equivalent time spent as work experience in the actual industry. You won't looked down upon because you have a PhD, but it will not give you a leg up against an MS software developer in most practical software development fields.

Comment: Technology certifications are not academic qualifications - they are outside the scope of this site.